# DriverManager.registerDriver() static method

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm studying the Java JDBC API and I've read that the first step of a database application is,of course, obtaining a connection to the DBMS.
Now, I know that DriverManager is one of the few (the sole class I've encountered so far) concrete classes in the package and it has a private constructor and just static methods (meaning that I can't instantiate it,even if I wanted to).
So, the DriverManager class (after JDBC 4.0) automatically loads the Driver interface implementation included in the vendor's driver (instead of manually call Class.forName("blahblah") to load the class) and the implementation classes themselves have a static initialization block in which they do something along these lines:

```
static {
  Driver driver=new cfully.qualified.name.DriverClass();
  DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
}
```

this registers the Driver implementation (if any) in the DriverManager,which in turn will be able to pass the URL to the database to all registered drivers in order to obtain the Connection object.
Now, I don't understand...how can the DriverManager class store (or register) the drivers?? those are instances of classes that implement java.sql.Driver,they're objects,so I would expect an instance of DriverManager to store (like,in an array, or some data structure) the registered drivers...but there's none as far as I know (I'm calling a static method!).
Can someone explain please??

Comment: I don't know what explanations do you expect because I don't understand what is written here. Clarify your specific problem and post a minimal example.

Comment: @RomanC and I don't know how to make you understand,since what the question asks is very clear.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't store them anywhere?

Comment: BTW: Most drivers nowadays (JDBC 4) are compatilble to [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) and therefore neither need `Class.forName()` nor `DriverManager.registerDriver()`. The code for this is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/0a00f10abb2d/src/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java#l502) and you do that with a `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` resource in the JAR.

Comment: @eckes When the JDBC driver is loaded through `ServiceLoader`, it still registers itself with `DriverManager`.

Comment: The Java sources are included with the JDK. You can see for yourself how `DriverManager` handles this (hint: classes can also have (static) fields to store things).

Answer (score 1):

This is what it does

```
public static synchronized void registerDriver(java.sql.Driver driver)
    throws SQLException {
    if (!initialized) {
        initialize();
    }

    DriverInfo di = new DriverInfo();

    di.driver = driver;
    di.driverClass = driver.getClass();
    di.driverClassName = di.driverClass.getName();

    // Not Required -- drivers.addElement(di);

    writeDrivers.addElement(di);
    println("registerDriver: " + di);

    /* update the read copy of drivers vector */
    readDrivers = (java.util.Vector) writeDrivers.clone();

}
```

So it registers the driver,  class and the class name of your driver in

```
private static java.util.Vector readDrivers = new java.util.Vector();
```

Then when some does `getConnection(String url.....)`

it will loop all the drivers in `readDrivers` trying this

```
Connection result = di.driver.connect(url, info);
if (result != null) {
   return (result);
}
```

So its up to the one implementing the java.sql.Driver to quickly decide if he is able to connect to the provided url

Comment: your answer isn't very clear to me, but nontheless it explains where it stores drivers' infos and what happens when a getConnection() method is invoked. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I did my best ; ), whats is not clear?